# How to rotate the object to get the landscape orientation given the points of the rectangle

Tags: python, opencv

I have trained a model to detect object of a rectangular shape and their corners. Below are the four examples
[image]

The purpose of corner detection is to set the landscape orientation. In some cases, however, the logic fails and the object is rotated upside down (180 degrees).

Below is the logic:

```
def save_poly_crop(vertices, img, vertex_top_left, vertex_top_right):
    img = np.array(img) 
    # RGB to BGR 
    # img = img[:, :, ::-1].copy()

    tag_area = list(cv2.minAreaRect(vertices))
    tag_area[0] = list(tag_area[0])
    tag_area[1] = list(tag_area[1])

    # get width and height of the detected rectangle
    # THIS IS FLIPPED:
    width = int(tag_area[1][0])
    height = int(tag_area[1][1])
    rotate_90_ccw = False
    rotate_90 = False
    if width < height:
        if vertex_top_left is not None and vertex_top_right is not None:
            if vertex_top_left[1] > vertex_top_right[1]:
                rotate_90 = True
            else:
                rotate_90_ccw = True
        else:
            rotate_90 = True
    
    box = cv2.boxPoints(tag_area)
    box = np.int0(box)

    src_pts = box.astype("float32")
    
    # coordinate of the points in box points after the rectangle has been
    # straightened
    dst_pts = np.array([[0, height-1],
                        [0, 0],
                        [width-1, 0],
                        [width-1, height-1]], dtype="float32")
    
    # the perspective transformation matrix
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_pts, dst_pts)

    # directly warp the rotated rectangle to get the straightened rectangle
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (width, height))
    
    if rotate_90:
        warped = cv2.rotate(warped, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
    if rotate_90_ccw:
        warped = cv2.rotate(warped, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

    return warped
```

vertex_top_left is the center of top-left rectangle (1), vertex_top_right is the top-right rectangle (2). Sometimes, it can be None (in case the detection fails), but always, there are at least 2 corners detected, so the logic should be updated in order to take into account all possible cases.

The current logic, however, contains an error which I haven't managed to find and fix. The vertices (these determine the object 0) are not necessarily ordered such that the top-left corner is at position 0 and the following corners follow in the clockwise direction. Sometimes, based on the width and height read from the tag_area, it seems that the object is rotated correctly (not rotated "too close to" 90 or -90 degrees) but when observing the image visually, it seems rather orientated as a portrait and it should be rotated 90 or -90 degrees.

here is an example of the vertices for which the logic works fine:

```
vertices = array([[  55, 1006],
       [  67,  357],
       [ 484,  364],
       [ 473, 1013]])
rectangle_top_left = array([[ -38, 1005],
       [ -38,  893],
       [  73,  893],
       [  73, 1005]])
vertex_top_left = cv2.minAreaRect(rectangle_top_left)[0]

rectangle_top_right = array([[-20, 464],
       [-18, 352],
       [ 93, 354],
       [ 91, 466]])
vertex_top_right = cv2.minAreaRect(rectangle_top_right)[0]

In the following case, however, the rotation fails:
vertices = array([[ 706,  751],
       [ 866,  726],
       [ 907,  986],
       [ 747, 1011]])
rectangle_top_left = array([[837, 707],
       [889, 699],
       [897, 752],
       [845, 759]])
vertex_top_left = cv2.minAreaRect(rectangle_top_left)[0]

rectangle_top_right = array([[ 870,  967],
       [ 922,  960],
       [ 930, 1012],
       [ 877, 1020]])

vertex_top_right = cv2.minAreaRect(rectangle_top_right)[0]
```

Note that the vertex_top_right and vertex_top_left don't necessarily have the exact same values as two points frop vertices array but they should be "close"

So the question is how to implement the logic to determine the correct rotation given the vertices of the main object that are not necessarily ordered "correctly"

Comment: You will need more than just the 4 vertices defining the corners, due to symmetry.

Comment: I mean, how do you tell right now that the image is upside down?

Comment: Is the detected vertex 1 always the top-left corner of your rectangle?

Comment: @Micka yes, 1 is always top-left corner

Comment: But you said in the question "The vertices (these determine the object 0) are not necessarily ordered such that the top-left corner is at position 0 and the following corners follow in the clockwise direction." Did I misread that? Because if vertex 0 in the input always corresponds to the point you labeled `1`, then that's the missing bit of info.

Comment: the vertices stored in vertices array are not necessarily ordered such that the top-left corner has the index 0. The labels indicating the corners, are, however, always the same relative to the orientation of the main orientation - label 1 always indicates top-left corner relative to the object of interest (labeled with 0)